# Why does my while loop terminate when count reaches zero?

Tags: c

How does `while` terminate when count becomes 0 without a condition like `count!=0`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int count=5;

void func(void);

void main()
{
    while(count--)
    {
        func();
    }
} 

void func(void)
{
    static int i=5;
    i++;
    printf("%d\t%d\n",i,count);
}
```

Comment: Use a `break` inside the scope of the while loop, that will exit the iteration.

Comment: @jwpfox, There's no `false` in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C Language `0` ( Zero ) is considered as being false. When you use `0` in any conditional statement, it will evaluate as false.

Ex: `if( 0 )` evaluates as false and the else code (if any) is triggered.

In your code, when `count--`  equals `0`, the while condition evaluates to `while (0)`.  Since an iteration of the `while` loop will only be triggered when the condition evaluates as true, the `while` loop will terminate at this point.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(condition)
```

Here the loop continues until the **condition** which renders to a boolean value, is  true. In C, 0 represents a **false** boolean value.

Therefore

```
while(count--)
```

In this case, the count value decrements in each iteration and when it becomes zero, the condition looks like **while(0)** which will break the loop as the *condition* became false.

Answer (score 1):

When a while loop tries to evaluate its conditional statement it casts the value to boolean. Integer values that are non-zero are treated as true and as a result the loop would continue and conversely zero would cast to false and stop the loop.

Answer (score 1):

the while loop  checks for a condition always so when count becomes zero while loop will have a false condition .

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop would probably work better here:

```
void main()
{
    for (int i=count; i > 0; --i)
    { 
        func();
    }
}
```

The reason a `for` loops fits your use case is that it both maintains a counter and has the ability to check for a termination condition.

Comment: `for (int i=count; i--; )` would suffice to avoid changing `count`.